# Java GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints

Tags: java

I have found many posts that talk about how to use GridBagLayout, however they are always the inverse of what I need.

For instance, in [this post](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) they the top row of buttons span the width while only one button is below it. My interest is mainly the first two rows.

[image]

But consider the inverse, I want exactly 1 button in row 1 to span the width of exactly 4 buttons in row 2 and any multiple from there on.

[=========Button========][=========Button========]

[button][button][button][button]
[button][button][button][button]

Comment: _and any multiple from there on._ What do you mean by this? I will post the code to achieve what you have described in the post, but I don't understand that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve the layout you're looking for.

```
public GridBagConstraintsFrame() {
    Container c = getContentPane();
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    {
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
        p.add(button1, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
        p.add(button2, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        p.add(button3, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 4");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        p.add(button3, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 5");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        p.add(button3, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 6");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        p.add(button3, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 7");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        p.add(button3, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 8");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        p.add(button3, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 9");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        p.add(button3, gbc);
    }

    {
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 10");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 7;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        p.add(button3, gbc);
    }

    c.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Gridbag constraints.");
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Here's how it looks.
[image]

If you want an explanation let me know in the comments and I'll try to explain every piece of code.

PS. This is a JFrame.